# Interesting saw tooth pattern in page load performance - Are there potential infrastructure / network / database settings to look at?

Tags: java, php, mysql, performance, nginx

I am running a performance test on a Drupal application that talks to a java backend via http requests. All application logic is handled in Java and Drupal is only a pass through for requests. There is caching of all GET requests going to Java on the Drupal side. So only < 10% of requests actually hit the java application. Drupal is running on on nginx with PHP-FPM with a load balanced set of 10 pods in kubernetes. Java app similarly runs on another set of 10 pods. Both Drupal and java applications talk to different mysql databases on the same mysql server.

We are seeing this strange page load performance pattern from the jmeter result. I know that this is not enough data to really say what is going on but was wondering if anybody has seen anything like this and are there simple network / db / php-fpm / nginx / loadbalancer settings that can cause such cycling.

This is from a test where around 300,000 requests were sent to the application in 3 hours.

[image]

The chart shows average response times for the requests on the y axis in a linear scale. x axis is time.

The application does not go down and the error rates does not go up because of this but just that the page speed goes up and down in clealry cyclic manner. Pods are not fully loaded - neither java nor Drupal and does not trigger scaling which should kick in at 50% processor loads. Memory usage is <50% on all pods. Database does not hit connection limits.

Any inputs and points are much appreciated. Will edit / update post if you have questions. Thanks in advance for your inputs / help.

Edit: Updated info about chart axis.

Comment: What is this chart measuring? Requests per second? Page load time? Other?

Comment: What is this graph's legend? What is the scale?

Comment: Thanks for looking into this and the comments. I have updated the post. Chart y axis is average response time, linear scale. y - axis is time.

Comment: What the heck is "19 03 40"??  How much time between spikes?  When are backups performed?  Do you have cron or EVENT jobs running?  Does something happen every 25 (or so) minutes?  Maybe Java's garbage collector?  Might something be resetting the cache?

Comment: 19 03 40 - 19 is date, 03 40 is the time. The x axis is time. It is the output generated by jmeter. No, there are no crons. Thanks for the tip about the Java garbage collector. The cache in Drupal is set with no expiry and is invalidated on specific requests and these don't happen during the test.

Answer (score 0):

We have solved this problem. Wanted to document this here for the benefit of anybody running into this / similar problems.

The issue was very interesting and we found it through taking xdebug profiles at multiple points in the saw-tooth pattern above.

We found that `PhPRedis->getMultiple` was taking upto 50% of the total time in requests during the peak of the saw tooth pattern and then drops back to low numbers at the trough.

We then found this documented in https://redis.io/docs/management/optimization/latency/. Verified that the redis server was indeed using transparent hugepage.

The fix was to change a kernel parameter to turn off transparent hugepage

```
echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
```

This addressed the saw tooth pattern and the average page load time stayed flat through the test.